# How to get sum value from SQL Server in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I try to get sum of all of my `TUTAR` column with SQL Server in C# but can't do it. When I try the code above it works fine.

```
string qry = "SELECT * FROM BENZIN WHERE DATE>='" + invoicedate + "' AND DATE<='" + invoicedate1 + "' AND PLATE= '" + plaka + "'";

conn.Open();

SqlDataReader dr = new SqlCommand(qry,conn).ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
    var item = new ListViewItem();
    item.SubItems.Add(dr["TUTAR"].ToString());
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

But when I try

```
string qry = "SELECT SUM(TUTAR) FROM BENZIN WHERE DATE LIKE '%" + yılcombobox.Text + "'";
MessageBox.Show(qry);

conn.Open();

SqlDataReader dr = new SqlCommand(qry, conn).ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
    yıllıktutar = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
}

MessageBox.Show(yıllıktutar);
```

it returns nothing. yılcombobox is a textbox and it contains selected year like 2017 or 2018 or something like that

Comment: You should not be using `LIKE` on a date.  *And* you should be using proper parameters rather than munging query strings.

Comment: Have you tried executing `qry` in your database editor? Does it show an error?
What value has `yılcombobox.Text`? Does it match to your `DATE` column?

Comment: Have you tried running the SQL that is shown in the Message Box directly, and if so does it return anything?  If you think the problem is with `GetValue(0)` then you could name the result, e.g. `SELECT SUM(TUTAR) AS MySum FROM...`, then use `dr["MySum"].ToString()`?  I also agree that this is not a safe way to construct SQL, as it's prone to SQL injection.

Comment: so how can I get sum(tutar) without using LIKE.I want to get all sum(tutar) in year of 2017 or which year selected.My date format is ex: 01.07.2017

Comment: @DjSucuk you could use BETWEEN for dates. There are plenty of ways to compare dates.

Comment: @RichardHansell yes I tried but it still get empty

Comment: @DjSucuk: First confirm that your SQL query returns anything at all.  *Then* debug the C# code.  You could be chasing a false assumption here.  Your first (working) query and second (non-working) query have more differences than just the use of `SUM()`.

Comment: Use `YEAR(DATE) = 2017` or whatever the equivalent syntax is for your particular database vendor.

Comment: When I try in my database side it returns the value but in c# no :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try like this;

```
string querysumtutar = "SELECT SUM(TUTAR) FROM BENZIN WHERE DATE LIKE '%" + yılcombobox.Text + "'"
SqlCommand cmdsumtutar = new SqlCommand(querysumtutar, baglanti);
SqlDataReader readersumtutar = cmdsumtutar.ExecuteReader();
while (readersumtutar.Read())
{
    sumtutar = Convert.ToInt32(readersumtutar.GetValue(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you read a SQL result with a single value, you should call [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of `ExecuteReader()`, because it lets you avoid the loop.

The most likely problem with your code is that you are performing a `LIKE` on a `datetime` column, which yields no results.

> I want to get all `sum(tutar)` in year of 2017 or which year selected

A bigger problem is that you are not parameterizing your SQL, making it an easy target of [SQL injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/601300/335858). You should fix both problems:

```
conn.Open();
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(TUTAR) FROM BENZIN WHERE YEAR(DATE)=@Year", conn)) {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Year", int.Parse(yılcombobox.Text));
    var res = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if (res != DbNull.Value) {
        yıllıktutar = res.ToString();
    } else {
        yıllıktutar = "<NULL>";
    }
}
```